# Subgroup of $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$ with positive entries

Tags: gr.group-theory, linear-algebra

Let $SL(n, \mathbb{R})$ be the group of $n \times n$ invertible matrices of determinant $1$ in real numbers. Let $G:=SL(n, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ be its subgroup $\{M  \in SL(n,\mathbb{R}) \mid M, M^{-1} \text{ both have non-negative entries}\}$. Is there any known results on this group? I am particular interest in how big (roughly) this group could be. I know $S_n \subset SL(n, \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0})$ (considering the permutation of a basis of a $n$- dimensional vector space), but I wish it could be much bigger than that.

Comment: The group is uncountable. It has a homomorphism $\det$ whose image includes the multiplicative group $\mathbb{R}_{> 0}$.

Comment: You are right, I should restrict to $SL(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Still, take the split torus $A=diag(e^{t},e^{-t})$.

Comment: I think elements of G are exactly diagonal matrices up to permutations.

Comment: @Asaf yeah, but I don't want those "trivial" examples, but if I restrict to $SL(n,\mathbb{Z})$, then I also want the coefficient to be real.

Comment: The definition should read "$M$, $M^{-1}$ both have non-negative entries" instead of "positive entries".

Comment: @PietroMajer So basically, this means it almost $S_n$ up to the scaling of coefficients? What is your reason?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/214574/19786

Comment: @dke Thank you! I think this answered my question!

Comment: @Li Yutong : just a geometrical argument. The matrix of a linear map $L$ in a given basis has non-negative entries iff the convex cone $C$ spanned by the basis is $L$-invariant: $L(C)\subset C$. This implies that for elements of $G$ $L(\mathbb{R}_{\le0}^n) = \mathbb{R}_{\le0}^n$, whence my conclusion above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is answered as Pietro says in http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CM/CM_1969__21_4/CM_1969__21_4_376_0/CM_1969__21_4_376_0.pdf

In general semigroup theorists have heavily studied maximal subgroups of semigroups of nonnegative matrices.

Again all maximal subgroups are isomorphic to the group of monomial matrices with nonnegative entries of appropriate rank.